# How to create variables by searching chars (substring) in string variable.. with loop and if statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, substring, character

'Hi, everyone. This variable has alphabetic and alphanumeric characters. If it has 'm' character is million and if it has 'Th.' is thousand.

```
df['mkt_value']

0       €15.00m
1        €1.00m
2       €100Th.
3        €3.00m
4        €900Th.
5        Free
```

'I pretend to i) identify if string variable is millions (m) or thousands (Th.) by creating a dummy variable. And then ii) use this dummy to get a new integer variable which millions be thousands'

```
#Desire output
df['mi']

0       15000
1        1000
2         100
3        3000
4         900
5         nan
```

'So, I first do a set up, then create a dummy with a loop and finally create a integer for the thousands:'

```
m = 'm'
th = 'Th'
dtype = {"money": "category"}
l_MKV = df['mkt_value'].tolist()
df['mi'] = df['mkt_value'].str.strip('mTh.€')

#loop for var dummy
for x in l_MKV:
    if m in x:
        df["money"]= 1
else:
       df["money"]= 0

# var integer for thousands: 1 million , 0 thousand
if df["money"] == 1:
        df["miles"] = int(df['mi']) * 100
        else:
                ALL['mi']
```

'The loop (for var dummy) is not working. I get:'

```
df["money"]

0       0
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       0
```

'And I get a syntax error for var integer without more specification

What I have missed?

Thanks for any help'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is the way you try to modified a single row in a series. For example, `df["money"] = 0` will actually set all rows to zero.

Rather than messing around with dummy columns, I would create a separate function for parsing the values and use DataFrame.apply():

```
def parse_amount(x):
    print(x[0])
    factor = {
        'm': 1000000,
        'Th': 1000
        }
    s = x['mkt_value'].strip('mTh.€')
    try:
        number = float(s)
        for f in factor.keys():
            if f in x['mkt_value']:
                number *= factor[f]
        return number           
    except:
        return 0

# import pandas as pd
# df = pd.DataFrame([{0:'€15.00m'},{0:'€1.00m'},{0:'€100Th.'},{0:'€3.00m'},{0:'€900Th'},{0:'Free'}])

df['money'] = df.apply(lambda x: parse_amount(x), axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, nevertheless, the ouput is float/number. I think there is an issue with dictionary items. I have tried to figure out, but I cannot fix it. Actual output
     mkt_value money
0 €15.00m 15.0
1 €1.00m 1.0
2 €100Th. 100.0
3 €3.00m 3.0
4 €900Th. 900.0
5 Free          0.0

Comment: Try now. Indeed, the `for f in factor.keys()` line...